# How to create field ID from string variable in java/android

Tags: java, android, field, textfield, programmatically-created

The purpose is that fields (EditText,Spinner,RadioGroup etc) and GUI (Layout/View) are totally created dynamically based on strings (names of field ids stored in the database) means each string will represent field id that will be used to differentiate all individual fields.

I have a String say,

```
String fieldName = "etAccountNo"; //id "etAccountNo" of field is placed in string "fieldName".
```

now I want to create a new EditText field programmatically whose variable name will be etAccountNo (that will be used to interpret EditText in android)
i.e.

```
fieldName = new EditText(context); //error here Incompatible types. required String but found EditText
```

means

```
//etAccountNo = new EditText(context); //error here
```

I understand this error but I need the possible solution for this objective.

Since GUI is programmatically/dynamically created so I must have to add field properties like setLayoutParams and setText etc. For example

```
etAccountNo.setText"My Field";
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Post your log and also proper code

Comment: Incompatible types. required String but found EditText

Comment: This isn't possible, but I'm curious as to why you'd want to do this. What problem are you trying to solve? The name of a variable, for instance, is for the benefit of a programmer, but you want to make changes at runtime...so the name doesn't matter.

Comment: You assigning string as Edittext. That is the reason for "Incompatible types" .

Comment: Can you post your code as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to dynamically create complete Android GUI (TextView / EditText / Spinner / RadioButton etc.) from strings (stored in sqlitedatabase)

Comment: You can create the GUI dynamically and can map them with those from database with id's instead of using same variables. By keeping id's for your strings in db and set the same id's to the corresponding views that you create.

Comment: Not exactly but If to continue What is datatype for sqlite database?

Comment: You can't set the id as String it should be an integer number, which is store in R.java file

Answer (score 2):

Base on the comment *You can create the GUI dynamically and can map them with those from database with id's instead of using same variables. By keeping id's for your strings in db and set the same id's to the corresponding views that you create*

If you want to achieve this you can create your views dynamically and then store their reference associated to the string in your database.

Example :

```
Hashtable<String, View> views = new Hashtable<>();

EditText et1 = new EditText(context);
views.put("etAccountNo", et1);

EditText et2 = new EditText(context);
views.put("blablabla", et2);
```

Once done you can get acces on your view using the field name into the database:

```
EditText accountNo = (EditText)views.get("etAccountNo");
```

Comment: That could be possible What I was looking for but I need to verify it

Comment: No Bro, etAccountNo should be the field id for EditText. i.e.    EditText etAccountNo = (EditText)views.get("etAccountNo"); because I need to use this variable as field id further.

Comment: @AbdulSaleem I think this is a good solution to your problem. Perhaps you don't understand the point of the views HashTable?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I can think of is to create a factory class that can map various `String`s to `View`s. For example:

```
public static View getViewForString(String string, Context context) {
    switch(string) {
        case "TextView":
            return new TextView(context);
        case "ListView":
            return new ListView(context);
    }
}
```

Or:

```
static <V extends View> Optional<V> getView(String name, Context context, Class<V> c){
    V view = null;
    switch (name) {
        case "TextView":
            view = c.cast(new TextView(context));
            break;
    }
    return Optional.ofNullable(view);
}
```

But this is pretty horrible, and I would encourage you to explore other methods for populating your UI.

As it's a programmatically generated View, it will not have an id value. You can assign one yourself however with `view.setId()` - so, you could use `view.setId("TextView".hashCode())`, or `view.setId(View.generateViewId())`.

Comment: and how can I get id for my new view? or how can I assign id of same name, as I have to work on view id further

Comment: As it's a programmatically generated `View`, I don't believe it will have an id value. You can assign one yourself however with `view.setId()` - so, you could use `view.setId("TextView".hashCode())`, or `view.setId(View.generateViewId())`.

Comment: Seems great. Please add your last comment in answer detail.

Comment: and why it is horrible?

Comment: and please elaborate how to call view from activity?

Comment: I have worked a detailed exact answer based on your first solution, I will upload it as answer